# Error: Specified cast is not valid while converting decimal to double

Tags: c#

I have a function as under

```
private double RoundOff(object value)

    {
        return Math.Round((double)value, 2);
    }
```

And I am invoking it as under

```
decimal  dec = 32.464762931906M;
var res = RoundOff(dec);
```

I am gettingthe below error

**Specified cast is not valid**

What is the mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting the `object` to `double` will attempt to unbox the object as a double, but the boxed object is a `decimal`. You need to convert it to a double after first unboxing it. Then you perform the rounding:

`Math.Round((double)(decimal)value, 2);`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct in terms of getting something that will run - but I wouldn't recommend using them.

You should almost *never* convert between `decimal` and `double`. If you want to use a decimal, you should use `Math.Round(decimal)`. Don't convert a decimal to double and round that - there could easily be nasty situations where that loses information.

Pick the right representation and stick with it. Oh, and redesign `RoundOff` to *not* take `object`. By all means have one overload for `double` and one for `decimal`, but give them appropriate parameter types.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to John's answer, if you want to use other number types than just decimal, you could use this code;

```
    private double RoundOff(object value)
    {
        return Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(value), 2);
    }
```